# error TS2305: Module 'ng' has no exported member 'IScope'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm upgrading an angular typescript project from angular 1.2 to angular 1.6 and from typescript 1.8 to typescript 2.1.

I've simply overwrote the angular.d.ts with the angular.d.ts@1.6.2 file and now I get this error. It appears that the new angular.d.ts exports the angular namespace instead of ng, but I'm not sure what's going on.

There are 212 files in this project, but this is the first one evaluated and this is the first line with that error.

```
    export interface Evaluation360Scope extends ng.IScope {
```